# Remove values from string using C#

Tags: c#

I have following string in my  aspx.cs page. These both strings are dynamic

`string fromDB = "12,24,25,45,67,78,90"` (its a dynamic string)

I have another string which has two or more values always as given below

```
string anotherStr = "24,67"
```

I am not getting an idea how to remove "anotherStr" values from "fromDB"

Finally I need `"12,25,45,78,90"`. I am not getting an idea how to do this using c#.

Comment: You can't simply because `anotherStr` doesn't exist in `fromDB`.If you wanted to exclude the values, you should do that before converting the list of numbers to a string. Preferably in the database itself

Comment: Split first by comma, parse each piece as int, throw in collection, split second by comma, parse each piece as int, remove from collection, join remaining using string.Join to add the commas back again.

Comment: did you try splitting by coma those strings and then iterating them like arrays? I could not be the best way, but it is easy

Comment: @Will parse to int is not needed, they just appear as numbers but that's just a guess

Comment: This all sounds like you should actually be using **integer arrays**: `int[] fromDB = { 12, 24, 25, 45, 67, 78, 90 };` and `int[] anotherArray = { 24, 67 };`. Having that would already make it a whole lot easier.

Comment: is it possible that you have duplicated items in either of strings?

Answer (score 2):

using Linq:

```
string.Join(",", fromDB.Split(',').Except(anotherStr.Split(',')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string fromDB = "12,24,25,45,67,78,90";
        string anotherStr = "24,67";

        var result = fromDB.Split(',').Except(anotherStr.Split(',')).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This splits the strings into arrays, and then excludes any entries from fromDB that are also in anotherStr.

*Note that the use of Except means that any duplicates will be removed from fromDB - as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547153/34092 .*

Comment: Thanks @ThePerplexedOne !

Answer (score 1):

Split your (hard) problem into multiple (easy) problems:

1. Convert your comma-separated strings into lists (or arrays) of strings (using e.g. `String.Split`).
2. Find out how to remove all list entries from one list from a second list (using e.g. `Enumerable.Except`).
3. Convert your list back into a comma-separated string (using e.g. `String.Join`).

For all of these simpler problems, solutions can be found here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
HashSet<string> all = new HashSet<string>(fromDB.Split(',')),
                toRemove = new HashSet<string>(anotherStr.Split(','));

foreach(var item in toRemove) {
     all.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that it will likely remove any duplicates from fromDB.

Comment: To be fair, my solution has the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `HashSet<T>` and *Linq*:

```
HashSet<string> exclude = new HashSet<string>(anotherStr.Split(','));

string result = string.Join(",", fromDB
  .Split(',')
  .Where(item => !exclude.Contains(item)));
```

Please, notice, that `Except` *removes* duplicates within `fromDB` while `Where` *preserves* them.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that it will likely remove any duplicates from fromDB. But, as you point out `Except` has the same issue. Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: @mjwills: `Where` (my code) preserves duplicates within `fromDB` when `Except` removes them.

Comment: Ah yes, you changed the code after I commented. But you are right, your edited code fits the bill perfectly. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

You split both strings to get two arrays, making the first a `List<string>` :

```
var fromDbList = fromDb.Split(',').ToList();

var anotherStrArray = anotherStr.Split(',');
```

You loop the second array, and delete its values from the first (which you cannot do on a `String[]`, hence the previous `ToList()`)

```
foreach (var valueToDelete in anotherStrArray)
{
    fromDbList.Remove(valueToDelete);
}
```

Then you join the (now modified) first array to get a single string:

```
var finalString = String.Join(fromDbList, ",");
```

Comment: Can you call Remove on an array?

Comment: Test this code with `"12,12,24,24,25,45,67,78,90"` and `"12,24"` as inputs.